# The difference between weakly ordered set and partially ordered set?

Tags: reference-request

I need a reference that discusses the difference between a weakly ordered set and a partially ordered set.

My understanding is that a weakly ordered set $<X, \succsim>$ is one where the partial ordering induces a total ordering on the equivalence classes of $X$. This is correct, yes?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct; equivalently, it’s a total preorder, i.e., a binary relation that is total, transitive, and reflexive. (Reflexivity actually follows from the first two conditions, but it’s part of the definition of a preorder, so I include it.)

Comment: Are you interested in the reference **as a reference**, or do you have some specific questions about the difference(s) between the two concepts?

Comment: I would like to have something I can cite.

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found a clear source I can site.

Louis Narens, Probabilistic Lattices (2015) in chapter 2 on page 29.

According to the text:

A **partial ordering** is one that is

- reflexive: $x \succsim x$
- transitive: $x \succsim y$ and $y \succsim z$ implies $x \succsim z$
- and anti-symmetric: if $x \succsim y$ and $y \succsim x$, then $x = y$

A **weak ordering** is one that is

- transitive (stated above)
- and connected: either $x \succsim y$ or $y \succsim x$.

A **total ordering** is one that is

- a weak ordering,
- and anti-symmetric (stated above).

"Note that a weak ordering is a partial ordering."